# SQL schema and ingredients list for cake recipe

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am new to PostgreSql and am working on an example database for learning purposes. I have a bakery database and a table for recipes and a table for ingredients. I am trying to understand the schema to connect the two tables such that the recipes table has a list of ingredients that references the ingredients table, but I am not sure if I need a 3rd table or if I can get away with just the two tables.

```
CREATE TABLE ingredients
(
    ing_id            SERIAL       PRIMARY KEY,
    name              varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    quantity          integer      NOT NULL
);


CREATE TABLE recipes
(
    rec_id                        SERIAL       PRIMARY KEY,
    name                          varchar(120) NOT NULL,
    list_of_ingredients           text         NOT NULL,
);
```

---

EDIT:
So let's say I have this in the ingredients table:

```
(1, flour, 40)
(2, eggs, 12)
(3, sugar, 23)
```

And this in the recipes table:

```
(1, cake, "3 flour, 4 eggs, 2 sugar")
```

I'm a bit confused on how to link the two tables.

---

The list_of_ingredients will need to reference the ingredients table as a foreign key. I understand that the whole point of NoSQL DBs is to allow for lists, so I'm not sure if I am approaching this totally wrong.

I will also write a Make_Recipe function that will take in a recipe and make sure there is enough ingredients, then will go ahead and decrease the ingredient quantity if it passes the above condition.

I have read through these posts, but they don't quite fit the bill:
[Database design for storing food recipes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225536/database-design-for-storing-food-recipes)
[Database Schema for Recipe/Ingredient/Measurement/Amount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45655382/database-schema-for-recipe-ingredient-measurement-amount)

Thanks for your time! Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean with "...they don't quite fit the bill"? I think it's a really good answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Database Schema for Recipe/Ingredient/Measurement/Amount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45655382/database-schema-for-recipe-ingredient-measurement-amount)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The relationship between recipes and ingredients is what is known as a many-to-many relationship - a recipe might contain any number of ingredients, while an ingredient might be used by any number of recipes.

In a relational database (and PostgreSql is a relational database), the way to create a many-to-many relationship is by introducing a bridge table.

In the case of recipes and ingredients, you will have three tables.
One table for ingredients, specifying the name of the ingredient (and possibly other ingredient related data, if you can think of such data).
Another table for recipes, specifying the name of the recipe, a description, the text explanation ect', and the size of the dish.
Then you have the bridge table, ingredientToRecipe, that will contain a one-to-many foreign key to the recipe table, a one-to-many foreign key to the ingredient table, and the quantity needed for that specific ingredient in that specific recipe.

Remember the size of the dish in the recipe table? That would be needed to calculate up or down scaling of the quantity of ingredients when scaling up or down the size of the dish.

So, a DDL for these tables might look something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE ingredients
(
    ing_id            SERIAL       PRIMARY KEY,
    name              varchar(255) NOT NULL
);


CREATE TABLE recipes
(
    rec_id          SERIAL          PRIMARY KEY,
    name            varchar(120)    NOT NULL,
    description     text            NOT NULL,
    DishSize        integer         NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE ingredientsToRecipes
(
    rec_Id          integer         REFERENCES recipes (rec_id),
    ing_id          integer         REFERENCES ingredients (ing_id),
    quantity        integer         NOT NULL,
    quantity_unit   varchar(100)    NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(rec_Id, ing_id)
);
```

Comment: Will this cause any problem since there is no PRIMARY KEY in ingredientsToRecipes? Or will 2 foreign keys substitute for the primary key?

Comment: Sorry, I somehow missed the primary key in the bridge table. Edited that in - the combination of the two foreign keys is the primary key of the table.